# Installing rails -- "rails new" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I'm trying to install rails. I'm new to this stuff, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I've got most things working, but when I actually try "rails new blog", I get the following error:

```
/Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir':    Permission denied - /rails_projects/blog (Errno::EACCES)
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:51:in `block in invoke!'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `call'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in `invoke!'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:15:in `empty_directory'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:103:in `create_root'
from (eval):1:in `create_root'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `block in invoke_all'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `each'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `map'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `invoke_all'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:226:in `dispatch'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I've searched around for a way to fix it (tried gem install rails several times, fiddled around with some other stuff), but I can't get it to work. I'd really appreciate some help. I'm working on OS X Lion, and have installed Ruby and RVM and all that. Can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Sasha

PS -- If I execute the above with "sudo", it returns this:

```
/Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

The thing is, I definitely have railties. And trying to reinstall via gem install doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Be root first, then try `rails new blog`

Comment: are you in your home directory? It seems your session has no permissions for creating files and dirs

Comment: No. The tutorial I'm following had me try to do this in a newly created rails_projects directory. But even doing the above command with "sudo" (which I think I'm using right) didn't work.

Comment: I'll post the sudo'd error above.

Comment: So it did work in my root directory. But what if I want to create a new rails file (as the tutorial I'm working with suggests) in a non-root directory?

Comment: Is the new directory under your home directory somewhere?  In addition when you install rvm the docs say do not install as sudo.  you should run the curl command in the $home user directory. https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: Don't run it as sudo, just change into a directory you have permission to write to. Running it as sudo will lead to even more permission issues down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue (on Mac). Was giving me the same error when i tried to create an application in a folder in HOME directory. But when i tried the same in one of user folders User/username it worked. I guess something to do with root permissions. Hope this helps.